# Jasper iReport: Error retrieving field value from bean

Tags: java, jasper-plugin

I am trying to pass list of days from bean to jasper plugin in Netbeans but i get an error.
I have followed this guide http://javabeansinjasper.blogspot.cz/2011/01/javabeans-as-datasource-in.html#comment-form

Error:

```
Error filling print... Error retrieving field value from bean : den 
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error retrieving field value from bean : den      
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRAbstractBeanDataSource.getBeanProperty(JRAbstractBeanDataSource.java:123)      
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRAbstractBeanDataSource.getFieldValue(JRAbstractBeanDataSource.java:96)      
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource.getFieldValue(JRBeanCollectionDataSource.java:109)      
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.setOldValues(JRFillDataset.java:1358)      
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.next(JRFillDataset.java:1259)      
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.next(JRFillDataset.java:1235)      
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.next(JRBaseFiller.java:1614)      
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:150)      
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:963)      
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:892)      
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:114)      
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:584)      
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:930)      
at com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.compiler.IReportCompiler.run(IReportCompiler.java:928)      
at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:1423)      
at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:2033)  
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Unknown property 'den' on class 'class java.lang.String'      
at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.getSimpleProperty(PropertyUtilsBean.java:1322)      
at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.getNestedProperty(PropertyUtilsBean.java:770)      
at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.getProperty(PropertyUtilsBean.java:846)      
at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtils.getProperty(PropertyUtils.java:426)      
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRAbstractBeanDataSource.getBeanProperty(JRAbstractBeanDataSource.java:111)      ... 15 more
```

Here is a bean:

```
public class ListDays {

public ListDays(String den) {
    this.den = den;
}

public ListDays() {
}

public String den;

public String getDen() {
    return den;
}

public void setDen(String den) {
    this.den = den;
}

public static Collection getSeznamDnu(){
    List<String> seznamDnu = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i<LocalDate.now().getMonth().length(LocalDate.now().isLeapYear()) ;i++){
            LocalDate prvniDenMesice = LocalDate.now().withDayOfMonth(1);
            seznamDnu.add(prvniDenMesice.plusDays(i).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EE dd")));}
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    return seznamDnu;

}
```

}

And here is a report:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="null" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="0f6a9791-50d4-4aff-9b3f-da0e5f528443">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="den" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[den]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="35" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="61" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="113" y="2" width="100" height="20" uuid="6b5fe0c5-60a2-4db6-96d6-cb9d065e17ff"/>
                <text><![CDATA[den]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="125" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="113" y="29" width="100" height="20" uuid="f588ecab-7ede-4e2c-80b9-994efcc45dd8"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{den}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band height="45" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="54" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band height="42" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

Thanks in advance. Been stacked on this for quite some time. Hopefully question is understandable.

Comment: You didn't post the code where you actually create the report and pass the bean model to jasper. And you're using an older article based on an even older version of jasper reports. What version of jasper are you using?

Comment: I am using iReport-5.6.0-plugin. The error occurs even while trying to preview data. I have tried to impelement it into application but still getting the same error.

Comment: The preview you cannot be helped with, the code yes. When you know what to do different in the code, you can replicate the change in the preview. You're doing something wrong and the error is a clear indicator it is in the way you pass the model along. As long as you refuse to do minimal effort to make your question more complete, you're on your own.

Comment: Thx for your response but I just did not want to add any confusing code because I was sure the mistake is somewhere in the code already posted. And finally, I have find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from some minor adjustments - creating separated package and class for generating collection and initialization of variable den - main problem was in this line:
 `seznamDnu.add(prvniDenMesice.plusDays(i).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EE dd")));}`

I was filling the collection with Strings instead of beans. Code changed to:

```
seznamDnu.add(new ListDays(prvniDenMesice.plusDays(i).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EE dd"))));}
```

And everything works fine. While looking at the code now, I also have to note that I didn't choose bean's name really well.